# Laravel views not loading

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing an application in laravel, it works fine on windows, loads the views

but when i move it over to my production machine on linux, some of the views wont load.

http://sentinel.weissconsultancy.com/

example there

application/views/widgets/servicesWidget.php is there, but it wont load it at all, it does the same for everything else in that folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this issue a lot.  I found that it was better for me to use "snake case" for this kind of issue because of the case sensitivity compatibility issues between windows and linux.  This is an annoying thing that I have found.

Change your view to be `widgets/services_widget.php` and reference it via

```
View::make('widgets/services_widget');
```

and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: thats really weird, i had the view set as the same case i had the file at, but changing it to this worked

Comment: +1 for a good research... reminds me of my transition from cake1.3 to 2.2 :P

Comment: @Andrew I found that even though you may have the same case,   View::make is making things lowercase before it looks for the file.   This works on windows because case does not matter.    On *inx systems, it does matter.